How to compare a column is not null in superset ( Metrics -> Custom SQL)?
I want to create a metric of Pivot 2: Actual/Target. But some Target is null. I wrote in Custom SQL as below but it did not work. I changed it to != Null or !=0, but it still does not work. Please help!
Case
           when TARGET is NULL then 0
             else SUM(Revenue)*100/Sum(TARGET)
END AS [%Actual/Target]

Thanks and regards
I changed it to != Null or !=0, but it still does not work.

you need to provide sample data, what you get, and your desired output.  and ofcourse part of the code

if you use mssql , you can use isnull function else if you use oracle you can use nvl function ...etc

Instead of testing the column target for NULL, test the calculation sum(target) they are not the same things. Also, flip the test to if sum(target) is greater than zero (hence avoiding the divide by zero and NULL at the same time): e.g.
select
   case when Sum(TARGET) > 0 then SUM(Revenue)*100/Sum(TARGET) else 0 end as pct
 , SUM(Revenue) as sum_revenue
 , Sum(TARGET) as sum_target
from t

Another way is to "nest" your query and move the percent calculation to the outermost (top) query, something like this:
select 
    case when sum_target <> 0 then sum_revenue / sum_target else 0 end as pct
  , sum_revenue
  , sum_target
from (
    select
       SUM(Revenue) as sum_revenue
     , Sum(TARGET) as sum_target
    from t
   )


create table t (
  id int
  , revenue decimal (12,2)
  , target decimal (12,2)
  );

insert into t
values 
  (1, 12.3, NULL)
, (2, 27.8, NULL)
, (3,NULL, NULL)
, (4, NULL, NULL);

select
   case when Sum(TARGET) > 0 then SUM(Revenue)*100/Sum(TARGET) else 0 end as pct
 , SUM(Revenue) as sum_revenue
 , Sum(TARGET) as sum_target
from t




pct
sum_revenue
sum_target




0
40.10
null



see this fiddle
